# Функция искажает данные передаваемого в него аргумента

Tags: c++, алгоритм, clion

При передаче аргументом символьного массива в функцию checking1() данные искажаются(смотрел в дебаггере).

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Validate.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

char* getString_User(){
    const int SIZE_BUF = 40;
    char buf[SIZE_BUF];
    cout << "Enter expression: ";
    return gets(buf);
}

int main() {
    char* str = getString_User();

    cout << std::boolalpha<< checking1(str) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

// Validate.hpp
#ifndef CALCULATOR_VALIDATE_H
#define CALCULATOR_VALIDATE_H
    
bool checking1(const char* string)  // 364362894++--(--)    --> true
{
    const char SPECIAL_SYMBOLS[] = "0123456789+-*/()";
    for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        char symbolString = string[i];
        bool flag = true;
        for(int j=0; SPECIAL_SYMBOLS[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            char symbolSpecialSymbols = SPECIAL_SYMBOLS[j];
            if(symbolString == symbolSpecialSymbols)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
#endif //CALCULATOR_VALIDATE_H
```

[image: Скрин1 из дебаггера(main.cpp)]

[image: Скрин2 из дебаггера(Validate.hpp)]

Comment: возврат указателя на локальные данные функции - то ещё приключение. Функция getString_User содержит UB.

Comment: Поподробнее про ub. Что это?

Comment: ub - это неопределенное поведение. Если в коде случилось UB, то дальше может быть все, что угодно. Например, программа может не работать, а может и работать, а может и диск форматнуть. В Вашем случае, Вы возваращете с функции указатель на локальный массив. По выходу с функции сам массив потеряется и указатель уже указывает на испорченные данные. Что делать? возвращать указатель на выделенную память через malloc или статично выделенную память

Comment: Или, раз уж у Вас с++, то используйте std::string.

Comment: По условиям задачи надо использовать C-строки

Comment: условие задачи выбрасывается и пишеться как нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `getString_User` возвращает адрес массива `buf`, который был создан внутри, то есть локально.

При завершении функции массив `buf` будет уничтожен. Адрес, который вернет функция будет указывать на место, где существовал массив. Однако, раз массива уже нет, на то же место в памяти уже могли быть записаны другие данные.

Можно решить проблему двумя (тремя) способами.

1. Передавайте в функцию `getString_User` уже созданный массив. То есть, создайте его в функции main. Так как массив будет создан вне  функции `getString_User`, она не будет его уничтожать.
2. Внутри `getString_User` создавайте динамический массив и возвращайте его адрес. Динамические массивы не ограничены областью видимости. Программист вручную управляет их временем жизни через операторы `new` и `delete[]`.
3. Для полноты ответа третий способ. Можно сделать массив `buf` статическим. Тогда он не будет уничтожаться по завершению функции и продолжит существовать до завершения программы. Однако использование статических (ровно как глобальных) переменных усложняет разработку, приводит к путанице, поэтому в настоящее время не рекомендуется.

```cpp
char* getString_User(){
    const int SIZE_BUF = 40;
    // массив живет вечно, никому память не отдает, данные не портятся
    static char buf[SIZE_BUF]; // не рекомендуется
    cout << "Enter expression: ";
    return gets(buf);
}
```

Советую глянуть про области видимости переменных, про висячие указатели и ссылки.

Comment: вот что только люди не выдумают, что бы не использовать std::string..

Comment: @KoVadim а ведь раньше народ работал с C-string'ами, пока не появились `std::string`... Да, последний значительно упрощает дело :)

Comment: На экземпляр std::string, как на любой объект, вполне успешно можно создать висячую ссылку и будут те же проблемы.

Comment: у статической переменной `static char buf[SIZE_BUF];` та же судьба будет. Повторный вызов функции исказит результат первого и пойдёт жара.

Comment: @4500zenja и сейчас работают. Но вот только человек в тегах поставил с++, а не чистый си. Был бы там си - кто бы вопросы задавал.